# How to find div into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get all the div (some div are append by ajax) into a parent div (to hide them). I've readed some documentation, but this not works :

```
<div id="contenu">            
 <div id="formFile"></div>
 <div id="documents"></div>
 <div id="options"></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="box_import"></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

$('div#contenu ~ div').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div#contenu > div').each(function(index){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

This gets all divs directly under `#contenu` and alerts their ID

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LKRkS/

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$('#contenu div').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Note:

- `$('#contenu div')` will give all `div` inside contenu including other nested `div`s
- `$('#contenu > div')` will give only the immediate children div

Comment: Yeah, and if you only have `div`s inside `contenu`, hiding the parent is much better. But if you have other content inside, you obviously have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently will alert their ID...
If you want to hide them instead, why not hide the parent?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenu").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contenu').find('div').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```